# Viewing all 'suggestions' in a solution

Tags: c#, rider

Newbie question, I've just switched from Visual Studio to Rider, so I'm still trying to get my bearings.

Trying to use the code analyzers and see the suggestions for the entire solution.
The errors/warnings I can see in the 'Errors In Solution' window but the suggestions are not listed there. Can I add them to that list somehow?, or is there a different window?

---

Edit:
It's not just the Roslyn analyzers, for example a spelling mistake shows up highlighted in the source as as 'suggestion'.
When opening the 'Errors in Solution' I would have expected those to also be there but they aren't.

Comment: Talking about like Roslyn analyzers or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jdphenix gave a link in the documentation where I was able to continue reading and found the answer.

The docs in question can be found here: [Find code issues in specific scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inspecting_Code_in_Specific_Scope.html)

First I had to do "Code => Inspect Code...", select solution and only after that an "Inspection Result" window becomes available, that's where it's listed.

Not very user friendly for new users :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to enable them.

[image: Rider Roslyn Analyzers]

See [Rider Roslyn Analyzers settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Roslyn_Analyzers.html) for the docs.

Comment: Those were set, should have given an example. A spelling mistake for example is highlighted if the source file is open as a 'suggestion', when opening the 'Errors in Solution" window it doesn't show up there.